# How to render ONLY one view?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.JS and Express web framework, I have a problem with the res.render()

I have this function:

```
exports.init = function(){

    return function(req, res, next) {   

        /* FORM CONTACT */
        if (req.body.contact){                      

            model.validateContact(function(e){              
                if (err) res.render('contacts', {'error': err})

                else {
                    model.sendContact(function(err){                                                
                        if (err) 
                            res.render('contacts', {'error': err})                              
                        else
                            res.redirect('/success')                                                        
                    })                                  
                }               
            })      

        }
        /* CONTACT */       

        res.render('contacts')
        console.log('after')
    }

}
```

Here I have a problem because res.render doesn't exist from the init function(I refer to the res.render inside the inner functions (validateCOntact and sendContact) so the last `res.render('contacts')` will be always executed.

Why the script is continuing its process if I render a page? How is it possible that I can do res.render() more then one time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
exports.init = function() {

  return function(req, res, next) {
    /* FORM CONTACT */
    if (req.body.contact){
      model.validateContact(function(e) {
        if (err) {
          res.render('contacts', {'error': err});
        } else {
          model.sendContact(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              res.render('contacts', {'error': err});
            } else {
              res.redirect('/success');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      /* CONTACT */
      res.render('contacts');
      console.log('after');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `return` after getting an error anyway, otherwise your main code will always be wrapped in `else` clauses.

Comment: Return is more useful when you only have more than 1-2 else-ifs indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just `return` after calling `res.render()`. ex:

```
if (err){
    res.render('contacts', {'error': err})
    return
}
```

Comment: I can't do the return INSIDE the inner functions, if i do that I will "exit" from there NOT from the main function(init function).

Comment: @Dali right, didn't pay attention to that, though you'd just need to return twice.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do **res.redirect** or **res.render** you should return, because if you don't you'll get the "Can't sent headers after.." error, since you'll be rendering another view.

Comment: I tried, It doesnt work, if i use return on the res.render (or res.redirect) inside the inner functions (validateContact or sendContact) I get "Error: Can't use mutable header APIs after sent." because the LAST res.render will always be executed.